# Databricks SQL array join

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks-sql

I have created query in databricks sql thats grouping text values by certain key.

The problem is that in some cases different date in grouping key value creates 2 separate rows

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBMDw.png)

I expect to have 1 row grouped by key and main applied date will be the highest one

```
Final AS
(
SELECT
    ,1.PRIMARY_KEY
    ,1.DUMMYCOLUMN
    ,1.DATE_START
    ,1.DATE_END
    ,ARRAY_JOIN(COLLECT_SET(Sales), ', ') AS TEST
FROM Contract
GROUP BY PRIMARY_KEY, DATE_START, DATE_END)


SELECT * FROM FINAL
```

Comment: Please don't link to images. It's preferred to put your sample as a formatted table in the question body. And providing a corresponding result table to your input is very helpful. Removes some ambiguity.

Comment: Broke my rule though and did look at your link and it's not obvious how that relates to either your input or expected output based on the query you've tried. This is a good reference for improving your question https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/